# How to extend and merge a list of objects with another list using lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

hopefully there is someone here with enough experience to guide me through this particular issue I've found.
So I am working with this peculiar API that returns an object akin to the following:

```
const api_response = {
  environment_list: ["dev", "non-prod"],
  member_list: [
    { id: "abc-456", name: "Homer", "last-name": "Simpson", role: "admin" },
  ],
};
```

The goal I'm trying to achieve is to create a new list that contains the user id, name, role, and environment based on the environment list above so it should look like this:

```
[
   { id: 'abc-456', name: 'Homer', role: 'admin', environment: 'dev' },
   { id: 'abc-456', name: 'Homer', role: 'admin', environment: 'non-prod' }
]
```

Now what I have done is the following:

I created a variable to isolate each value that will be be merged:

```
const userList = _.map(api_response.member_list, (data) => ({
  id: data.id,
  name: data.name,
  role: data.role,
}));

const environmentList = _.map(api_response.environment_list, (data) => ({
  environment: data,
}));
```

Then these two were merged as one list of objects:

```
const extendAndMergeList = _.map(environmentList, (data) =>
  _.map(userList, (items) => ({ ...items, environment: data.environment }))
);
```

And the output is close enough to my final product which is:

```
[
  [
    { id: 'abc-456', name: 'Homer', role: 'admin', environment: 'dev' }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 'abc-456',
      name: 'Homer',
      role: 'admin',
      environment: 'non-prod'
    }
  ]
]
```

I'm probably doing something silly but would love to have some guidance in how to trim this from a list of lists to a list of objects.

another look at all the steps I took:

```
const _ = require("lodash");

const api_response = {
  environment_list: ["dev", "non-prod"],
  member_list: [
    { id: "abc-456", name: "Homer", "last-name": "Simpson", role: "admin" },
  ],
};

const userList = _.map(api_response.member_list, (data) => ({
  id: data.id,
  name: data.name,
  role: data.role,
}));

const environmentList = _.map(api_response.environment_list, (data) => ({
  environment: data,
}));

const extendAndMergeList = _.map(environmentList, (data) =>
  _.map(userList, (items) => ({ ...items, environment: data.environment }))
);
```

Thank you again for any helpful response!

Comment: I decided to go ahead and flatten the list for now using the following:
```
_.flatten(extendAndMergeList)
```
and it is doing what i'd like it to. But i'm sure i'm probably doing something funny here.

Comment: Check out the second part of my answer, I believe this is the best method to do this, as lodash can be a bit unefficient in this case. (Flatten adds a few more operations in your code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to use the [`_.flatten` method of lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#flatten) to achieve this:

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

const data = _.map(api_response.environment_list, e => 
    _.map(api_response.member_list, m => ({
        id: m.id, 
        name: m.name, 
        role: m.role, 
        environment: e
    })
); // This step achieves the exact same thing that you have achieved up until now in your question.

const flattenedData = _.flatten(data); // This is the method you need to make the array "flat".

console.log(flattenedData);
```

You could also attempt to do this without using lodash in this, a bit more efficient, way:

```js
const output = [];
for (const e of api_response.environment_list) {
    for (const m of api_response.member_list) {
        const obj = {
            id: m.id, 
            name: m.name, 
            role: m.role, 
            environment: e
        };
        output.push(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, this is exactly what I was looking for. thank you so much.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out you do not need lodash and can use the `Array.prototype.flat()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Answer (score 1):

i believe you can use a simple map like this:

```
const userList = _.map(api_response.environment_list, (env) => ({
  ...(_.pick(api_response.member_list, ['id', 'name', 'role' ])),
  environment: env
}))
```

for every enviroment you return an object with the keys you want and add the environment prop

you can also use _.omit instead of _.pick to remove the "last-name" prop instead of selecting all those want.